# String: Only Remove Numbers Following a Quotation Mark

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string similar to `the "cow"1 jumped "over"2 the moon and the "spoon"3... this happened 123 times`
I want to remove only the numbers following a quotation mark:
`the "cow" jumped "over" the moon and the "spoon"... this happened 123 times`

Comment: How about the following: `(?<=\")\d+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

See the regex pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/Q8UwEo/1).

```
import re
string = 'the "cow"1 jumped "over"2 the moon and the "spoon"3... this happened 123 times'
pat = r"(?<=\")(\d+)"
out = re.sub(pat, "", string)
print(out)
```

```
the "cow" jumped "over" the moon and the "spoon"... this happened 123 times
```